# Validación con jQuery y Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, bootstrap-4

Alguien que me enseñe a hacer una validación con jQuery o que me guíen de como poder hacerlo al momento de estar escribiendo en input con diseño de bootstrap 4?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que al momento de dejar los campos me valide y cambie de color así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la validación la requiero en el momento que se cambia de input no al hacer click en el botón de envió de mi form.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Saludos.

Comment: A groso modo lo que necesitas es un javascript que cada vez que se iserte una tecla compruebe el  form y si no cumple lo esperado que le diga al css que se ha de poner rojo. aqui un link a algo de JS para lo que buscas https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp , lo adaptas y si algo no funciona bien, es cuando deberias de preguntar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otra forma de hacerlo teniendo el mismo resultado es mediante el siguiente codigo, igualmente al perder el foco y comparar el valor del input se agrega la clase "is-invalid" y cuando tiene contenido remueve la clase correspondiente

El codigo de HTML y JavaScript es el siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").focusout(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length == 0) {
      $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
    }
    /*
           
    */
    console.log('lost focus');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <!-- validacion con clase is-invalid-->
      <form>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <label for="validationDefault03">City</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault03" placeholder="City" required>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es el resultado cuando no tienes valores en el campo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias también me ayudo mucho!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes agregar la clase **is-valid** o **is-invalid** dependiendo de la validación al input. Aqui un ejemplo cuando pierde el focus el input

```
$('#inputnombre').on('focusout',function(){
    var texto = $(this).val();
    if(texto.length > 0)
        $('#inputnombre').addClass('is-valid')
    else
        $('#inputnombre').addClass('is-invalid')
});
```

Para el HTML, quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputnombre">Email address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputnombre" aria-describedby="inputNombre" placeholder="Nombre">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Pruebalo y me dices.

Comment: Muchas gracias es lo que necesitaba me funciono a la perfección. Y como me lo comentas yo ya valido con regular expression mis campos.